# How to change value of min validation after reponse from API in Formik Validation schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I want to change the the min validation value after i receive the response from server ,
Here is the code

```html
 const form =useFormik({
      initialValues:{name:'',email:'',price:0},
      validationSchema:Yup.object({
          'email':Yup.string().required("Email required").email("Invalid email"),
          'name':Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
          'price':Yup.number().min(0,"Invalid price")
      })
  })
```

When page load i will receive new min value from the API

```html
useEffect(()=>{
//API call

},[]);
```

Now I want new validation where min validation value is 500

```html
  form=useFormik({
      initialValues:{name:'',email:'',price:0},
      validationSchema:Yup.object({
          'email':Yup.string().required("Email required").email("Invalid email"),
          'name':Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
          'price':Yup.number().min(500,"Invalid price")
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just create a variable and set the value?

```
var apiValue = 0;

useEffect(()=>{
  //API call

  apiValue = returnedApiValue //e.g. 500

},[]);

'price':Yup.number().min(apiValue,"Invalid price")
```